# How to modify an AuthenticationProvider for a webapp without overwriting existing settings?

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell

At the minute I am using `New-SPAuthenticationProvider` to set fields and then updating the web application with `Set-SPWebApplication`. However, this approach overwrites any existing Authenication Provider properties. Is there a way to do this that will retain the existing?

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior when you update a web application with new authentication provider using the commands.
You will need to manually assign the parameters in PowerShell commands or update the authentication manually via Central Administration.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I'm wondering if there's another option other than New-SPauthenicationProvider, or how is it possible to assign the parameters in powershell?

Comment: @falsenono I haven’t been able to find an alternative command for it. Can you explain a bit more about “Authentication Provider properties”? If you are configuring a new authentication, that should be an irreversible action, right? See a reference here: https://techdocs.broadcom.com/us/en/ca-enterprise-software/layer7-identity-and-access-management/single-sign-on-agent-for-sharepoint/12-52sp1/configuring/configure-sharepoint/modify-an-existing-classic-authentication-to-claims-based-authentication-using-powershell.html

Comment: I want to switch claims based authentication on and enable kerberos. But I want to keep all the other properties set as they are. I can't find a way to do this without completing creating a new auth provider and setting it in the web app. But doing that means the existing properties are all overwritten

Comment: @falsenono You are right, that is the expected behavior, since you are switching to another authentication method.

Comment: once I have made the switch to claims based, is it possible to later enable/disable kerberos without creating a new auth provider again?

Comment: @falsenono Yes, that is possible. These links for your reference: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/configuring-kerberos-authentication-on-share-point-2013-2016-web-application/ / https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cfe8cda0-706a-4fb1-8c22-839fe3a7eab0/how-to-disable-kerberos-authentication-for-sharepoint-2010?forum=sharepointadminprevious

Comment: thank you. I'd like to be able to do this using powershell if possible